# Adding the required jars to the Application under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This is a general query , but i am asking as you people are experienced and would have come across this type of  situation before .

I have imported an existing Application under Eclipse IDE , which is missing some jars , I need to add some jars to make it get compiled .

Now i have  some 100 jars within a folder . how can i find what jar to add for that missing class ??

Please suggest me any ideas for this , thank you very much .

Thank you very much .

Comment: Try Ctrl-1 on one of the classes not being found.  Eclipse may be able to suggest the correct jar to add to the build path.

Answer (score 1):

If the project comes with a `/lib` folder containing some jars, add all of them. Right click the project > Build Path > Configure Build Path > "Libraries" tab -> Add jars

If this is your project, or you can do something about it, consider using a dependency management tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: Despite that, I think that you (OP) should consider using some dependency management tool. A 100 jars is 'more than adequate' to justify the usage of some Apache Ivy or Apache Maven. I.e. the Eclipse Maven plugin will keep your project configuration for you.

Comment: That's not a good solution, if the folder contains different versions of the same library. You should at least check the versions and look if you can determine the correct version.

Comment: @PedroKowalski 100% agreed, but if the project isn't built with maven support, perhaps it would be less time consuming to stay that way. Anyway, I'm adding the maven suggestion

Comment: @dunni - my impression was that the project ships with its jars. In that case it has been the responsibility of the authors to have "good" jars in the lib folder

Comment: That's right. But i think, you also know the (not always good) reality :) And i just wanted to mention it.

Comment: I agree with Dunni , if i imported all the 100 jars then versioning is also a problem . (As the same class is present in diffeent jars)

Comment: @user974802 if the project is made by someone else, tell him/them to check their distributed jars. You can't do much, apart from removing the jars with the same name  but different version